How to check and get the type parameter of a type parameter in Go
I have a generic function func f[T any]() T {} and I can get the type of T by instantiating it as a variable var t T
But what if I want to pass a generic struct to a generic function?
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func f[T any]() {
    var t T
    fmt.Printf("got type %s", reflect.TypeOf(t))
}

type G[T any] struct{}
type InnerG struct{}

func main() {
    f[G[InnerG]]()
}

It prints out got type main.G[main.InnerG]. How do I instantiate the inner generic struct?

The answer is: You cannot (and you probably shouldn't anyway). Your usage of generics probably is flawed. Your f is parametrised with a unconstrained type T. T could be func(uint16)complex128 . Such a T has no "inner" struct, it not even is a struct type it not even is itself generic. This probably is a XY problem and the real solution might be completely different, probably you should use interfaces and not generics.

Do you want to instantiate G[InnerG] or G with a different type parameter or InnerG?

@blackgreen I can instantiate T in the function, but I need to instantiate it if it has a parameter type. But I only need it for the G struct, that's why the solution worked in my answer.

I have a hard time understanding what is the concrete use case of this code. If you have a generic function, why does it have to do some black magic with reflection only for a specific argument type?

@blackgreen I'm dealing with parsing, and I'd like to have wrappers around the type. e.g. f[Wrapper[MyResponse]](). It's crazy but I wanted so, I think it looks nice

reflect.Type uses assembly code to build the name. I couldn't find any way to access it.
But if you control the outer type parameter you can add the field t T to G struct and it will become accessible with `reflect.FieldByName("t")
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

func f[T any]() {
    var t T
    fmt.Printf("got type %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(t))
    typeOf := reflect.TypeOf(t)

    if typeOf.PkgPath() == "main" && strings.HasPrefix(typeOf.Name(), "G[") {
        // T is a generic type
        tField, found := typeOf.FieldByName("t")
        if !found {
            panic("field t is not found in G")
        }
        fmt.Printf("got inner type: %s \n", tField.Type)
    }
}

type G[T any] struct {
    t T
}
type InnerG struct{}

func main() {
    f[G[InnerG]]()
}

Result:
got type main.G[main.InnerG]
got inner type: main.InnerG 

You can instantiate the reflect.Type like so:
reflect.New(tField.Type).Elem().Interface()

It will return any though.

"but you can cast it" no as there are no type casts in Go.

@Volker you can do switch u:=t.(type)

Type switches (and/or type assertions) are not casts.
